# SQL string concatenation for select output value with if

Tags: mysql, sql

Having a table named `blubb` with 3 fields: `id`, `year` and `week`

```
CREATE TABLE blubb (
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `year` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `week` int(11) NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO blubb (year, week) VALUES (2017, 1);
INSERT INTO blubb (year, week) VALUES (2017, 2);
INSERT INTO blubb (year, week) VALUES (2017, 3);
INSERT INTO blubb (year, week) VALUES (2017, 4);
INSERT INTO blubb (year, week) VALUES (2017, 5);
INSERT INTO blubb (year, week) VALUES (2017, 6);
INSERT INTO blubb (year, week) VALUES (2017, 7);
INSERT INTO blubb (year, week) VALUES (2017, 8);
INSERT INTO blubb (year, week) VALUES (2017, 9);
INSERT INTO blubb (year, week) VALUES (2017,10);
INSERT INTO blubb (year, week) VALUES (2017,11);
INSERT INTO blubb (year, week) VALUES (2017,12);
INSERT INTO blubb (year, week) VALUES (2017,13);
INSERT INTO blubb (year, week) VALUES (2017,14);
INSERT INTO blubb (year, week) VALUES (2017,15);
```

The goal is to get a select statement which concatenats `year` and `week` with a `W` in between **and** which will always select the week with two digits. So if week value is `1` i need `01`

I've accomplished it like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    IF(week < 10, CONCAT(year, 'W0', week), CONCAT(year, 'W', week) ) as year_week,
    year,
    week
FROM
    blubb
```

Result and also expected result:

```
year_week   year    week
2017W01     2017    1
2017W02     2017    2
2017W03     2017    3
2017W04     2017    4
2017W05     2017    5
2017W06     2017    6
2017W07     2017    7
2017W08     2017    8
2017W09     2017    9
2017W10     2017    10
2017W11     2017    11
2017W12     2017    12
2017W13     2017    13
2017W14     2017    14
2017W15     2017    15
```

The question is: Is there another better, cleaner way of solving this? 
Thank you

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03bbe2/1/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LPAD :

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(year, 'W', LPAD(week, 2, '0'))as year_week,
    year,
    week
FROM
    blubb
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `LPAD`

```
select concat(year, 'W', lpad(week, 2, '0')) as year_week,
       year,
       week
from blubb
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=8961403675cfd74f0bc98ce6e307a04f)